# iPhone 5 Car Bluetooth Issue with Incoming Phone Calls

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

I have an iPhone 5 running iOS 10.2 and a 2015 Chevy Mailbu with Bluetooth capability for calls and streaming audio (non CarPlay).

The problem I have is when I am **receiving** calls (everything else works fine).  When a call comes in and I answer it, regardless if I press the phone button on the steering wheel or the answer button on the phone, the iPhone immediately switches to its internal speaker  I have to manually switch it back to the "Bluetooth headset" (car speakerphone) for the audio to work properly.

I have tested this in 3 different cars - the Chevy, an Infiniti and a truck with an aftermarket Kenwood radio.  The problem is present in all three vehicles.  I have also tested with a Windows Phone and and Android phone and both phones work with the cars properly so it's definitely a phone issue.

I have rebooted the iPhone, deleted the profile and re-paired with the radio and I have even reset the iPhone to factory default and re-paired it as if it was new.  The problem persists no matter what I do.

**Does anyone know what the issue is or what I have to do to solve it?**

[Update]
Problem still persists after **iOS 10.3, didn't resolve the issue.**

Comment: I have an Anker SoundSync in my truck and I have to do the exact same thing when answering a call.  It's very frustrating and I haven't been able to find a solution yet, either.

Comment: What version of iOS do you have installed on your iPhone 5?

Answer (score -1):

I think this will fix it :

Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Scroll down to interaction section -> Call Audio Routing -> Choose headset

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Good answers provide supporting info as to why they are correct and/or will address the OP's question.  See [answer] for tips on providing good answers.  You can [edit] your answer to include why you believe this will work. - From Review