# Blutooth stopped connecting to car automatically

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

My iPhone5S always AUTOMATICALLY connected with my car radio upon entering the car and when I made or received a call by pressing the button on the steering wheel of my 2011 Chevy Mailbu, I would hear the call through the car's radio speaker, no problem.

Then with no changes made on my end, bluetooth quit connecting automatically. I can still make a receive a call by pressing the button on the steering wheel but the call is now NOT heard thru the car speaker. I can make it use the car speaker by pressing on the round "audio" icon that appears on the iPhone screen and the pressing "my vehicle" on the next box that appears. However, having to hit these two buttons on the phone while is too dangerous while driving.

I have turned bluetooth off and back on. I have re-paired the iphone to the car. I even installed the latest Apple 11.2.6 software upgrade, all to no avail. So for now I can use the steering wheel button to make/receive calls but only hear the call thru the speaker in the iPhone, not the car. For years the bluetooth worked correctly, automatically connecting to the car upon entering the car and all calls came thru the radio speakers. This bluetooth auto-connect stopped working about a week ago. Apple support on the phone twice could not solve the problem.

Has anyone had this same problem and fixed it. It is driving me nuts as I have tried everything I know of and have read about on google. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See this nearly exact same post:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/267124/iphone-5-car-bluetooth-issue-with-incoming-phone-calls  Unfortunately, no answers as of yet.

Comment: I got almost the same problems on my 2017 BMW 1series. But I am not able to reproduce this issue. It seems to depend on how I use the iPhone in my car. First problem to eliminate is to charge the iPhone in the car, when the phone is paired (I really mean paired, not connected) via Bluetooth already. Many cars got problems with phones connected via USB and paired via Bluetooth at the same time. Do you plug-in your phone when you go driving? If yes, try wihout plugging it in. Since I avoid this I didn't experience any further problems... maybe this helps.

Comment: 2015 Chevy, same issues. I find that connection is more reliable when I start car manually, it NEVER connects any more if I used remote start. It connects fine if I manually hit the MyLink connection in phone bluetooth menu, but incredibly inconsistent if I wait for it to connect automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try making a call using the iPhone while in your car and making sure it has the Chevy MyLink selected.

This happened to me a while back and it was very annoying (iPhone 6s and 2015 Chevy). Some how my default was changed from using the car speakers to using speaker phone.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/230407)

Comment: Thank you. I changed my answer to be more “answer like”.